# base-package in component-scan pick up the wrong subpackage

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have put most of the class under

```
  com.company.productline.product  -- classpath 1
```

within that class path there will be service, web, domain, i18n... subpackages.

For some reason, there is another service bean I wrapped in a jar, which should work for the whole productline, hence it is under

```
  com.company.productline    -- classpath 2
```

So in applicationContext.xml, the base-package for component-scan have to compromise to one level up, as classpath 2 instead of classpath 1, like this

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.productline">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
  </context:component-scan>
```

Then to make Spring to scan @Service or @Component across the whole application even within that jar file.

However, now in applicationContext there is an error saying:

```
 Annotation-specified bean name 'someServiceClass' for bean class
 [com.company.productline.i18n.someServiceClass] conflicts with existing, 
 non-compatible bean definition of same name and class 
[com.company.productline.product.i18n.someServiceClass]'
```

The problem is Spring seems find a bean class under a false package `com.company.productline.i18n.someServiceClass` without the `product` in the middle, but here are what I can confirm:

1. There is not a class/classpath under the package `com.company.productline.i18n.someServiceClass`, but there is a class under `com.company.productline.product.i18n.someServiceClass`.
2. The class `someServiceClass` does have a @Component annotation.

But if I take one level down of the classpath in `base-package`, the error is gone:

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.productline.product">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
  </context:component-scan>
```

the class is defined like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "request")
public class SomeServiceClass implements CurrentRequest {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public Locale getCurrentLocale() {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        return localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

}
```

So really not sure what's going on and why have this problem.

The application is running on Spring 3.1.0 on STS 2.9.1

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm that your applicationContext doesn't have a manual bean wiring looking for a class com.company.productline.i18n.someServiceClass? Do a search of your entire project for that line, see what it comes up with.

Comment: Thanks @ninn. I think in that case then the class name should appear within the xml right? I did a whole project search but didn't find the class name show up in any xml file, neither properties file.

Comment: Yes it would. This is definitely strange and nothing I've heard of happening before. It almost sounds like you recently moved your "someServiceClass" to a new package but your packaging structure and server don't know it. Try cleaning up your service (deleting your deployable war, ear, etc) from the server it self. Then do a full clean-install, I'm assuming your using Maven, and deploy again.

Comment: @ninn. Thank you. First the error is from Eclipse after I build the project. Then I delete the `target` folder and deployment folder under vFabric server instance, then rebuild the project, but doesn't help.

Comment: I have updated the question with class definition, may be the class itself has issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ninn is correct. There is no other possibility but only a class with same bean name within the application.

The reason the project search doesn't work out in this case is that we have another jar file with the same service class. I wasn't know that until noticed. After remove the class within the source code then the error is gone.

Thanks ninn.